# how to display a map as vector data from a url

Tags: javascript, html, openlayers, openlayers-3

I am studying the workshop of OpenLayers as mentioned here in this link:

```
https://openlayers.org/workshop/en/vector/geojson.html
```

the code when run it should display a map as vector data according to the geojson file mentioned in the URL as shown in the
code below.

the problem I am encountering now is, when I run the code, no map appears only the plus and minus buttons with dark background
but the vector data does not appreciate.

to solve this issue, I attempted changing the formate of the file from geojson to be json as well as attempted to manipulate
the path to the file as follows:

**attempts**:

I also adapted the code to be as follows:

```
url: './data/countries.geojson',
url: '/data/countries.geojson',
url: 'data/countries.geojson',
```

but non of them worked nor resulted in showing the map.
please let me know how to render or display a map as vector data from a URL

**main.js**:

```
   import 'ol/ol.css';
import GeoJSON from 'ol/format/GeoJSON';
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import VectorLayer from 'ol/layer/Vector';
import VectorSource from 'ol/source/Vector';
import View from 'ol/View';
import {Fill, Stroke, Style, Text} from 'ol/style';

var style = new Style({
  fill: new Fill({
    color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)',
  }),
  stroke: new Stroke({
    color: '#319FD3',
    width: 1,
  }),
  text: new Text({
    font: '12px Calibri,sans-serif',
    fill: new Fill({
      color: '#000',
    }),
    stroke: new Stroke({
      color: '#fff',
      width: 3,
    }),
  }),
});

var vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
  source: new VectorSource({
    url: 'data/countries.geojson',
    format: new GeoJSON(),
  }),
  style: function (feature) {
    style.getText().setText(feature.get('name'));
    return style;
  },
});

var map = new Map({
  layers: [vectorLayer],
  target: 'map-container',
  view: new View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 1,
  }),
});
```

**index.html**:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>OpenLayers</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-container {
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        background-color: #04041b;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-container"></div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you will see an error in your Browser developers console (Right click -> Inspect). Please post the error here and it will be easier to help you.

I suspect that one if these points will fix your issue:

1. Check if `countries.geojson` is in your `data` folder. If not a 404 will apear in your console.
2. Check if `countries.geojson` is valid geojson using a lint like https://geojson.io. If not your console says something about an invalid json format. It doesn't matter so if the extension is `.json` or `.geojson`.
3. Be sure that you open the `index.html` from a local server (https protocol), opening it directly from folder (file protocol) won't load the file and would show a CORS error in your Javascript console.

Comment: Also some server types (particularly IIS) will return 404 if the file extension is not defined in the MIME type settings. If using IIS you may need to open the MIME types settings and add extension `.geojson` as MIME type `application/json` (or you could rename the file as `.json` which should be in the default settings).

Comment: @Mike would you please tell me exactly how to find web browser developer and where to right click

Comment: If inspect is not available from right click try using the F12 key